# Page Header and Footer not visible

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2011

I have a report created by someone else; the page header and footer are not visible in the Design view nor are they listed in the Section Expert.

How do I make them visible again?  I have both CR2008 & 2011 and neither show those sections.

Comment: No, it's a stand-alone report.

Comment: sub-reports can be stored, in which case it would look like a stand-alone report.  try inserting it into a new blank report in the detail section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are probably hidden by setting of CR. To make them visible right click on report and turn on hidden sections

[image]

Hope it helps

Comment: Hidden sections were set as visible.  I unchecked it and then re-checked it and they appeared.

Comment: @PatrickMcGuire Probably some CR bug then. Glad it helped you